# Cannot redirect http to https in aws ec2/route53 with domain on godaddy

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

i had a domain and hosting in godaddy and i wanted to transfer the hosting in aws services and keep the domain in godaddy.

I have created an ec2 instance which contains a web application in .net and a rds instance containing the database of that application. Then i created a load balancer which contains the ec2 instance, a launch configuration and an auto scaling group as the tutorials said. Finally i went for route53.

I created a hosted zone with the following:

1) A record with alias from domain.com to point to dualstack-load-balancer
2) nameservers
3) SOA
4) delivered the MX records from godaddy
5) CNAME for www.domain.com to point to load balancer also (otherwise www.domain.com didnt work)

Since i had ssl from godaddy and i wanted to keep it by goind to aws services, i created https listener and i uploaded the ssl certificate.

So every url works for my website, like http://domain.com, https://domain.com

But the problem is when i am trying to do the redirection for every url to go from http to https

I tried many ways with url rewrite, with rules in web.config and with c# code in application begin request in global.asax.

Most of the ways i found them in here in many questions.

With a few ways i managed to do the redirection but i get 2 errors.

First i get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS ...
and then and in most cases i get this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)
I have no idea what to do now so the redirection works. I have done something wrong when setting up everything? Can someone please explain to me whats going wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you